# How can I make this program execute and can I make a loop that can go back to the selection?(Do you want to try again?)

Tags: java, loops, switch-statement

How can I make this program execute and can I make a loop that can go back to the selection?(Do you want to try again?)

```
package javaapplication6;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication6 {  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);
    int choose;
    System.out.println("MENU");
    System.out.println("1.Accounts");
    System.out.println("2.Age");
    System.out.println("3.Balance");
    System.out.println("4.Quit");
    System.out.println("Enter Selection:");
    choose=a.nextInt();

    switch(choose){
      case 1: 
        String name,password;
        System.out.println("Enter username:");
        name=a.nextLine();
        if("Nathalie".equals(name))
        {
          System.out.println("Enter password:");
          password=a.nextLine();
          if("Dandan".equals(password)){
            System.out.println("Welcome "+name+" "+password);
          }
          else
          {
            System.out.println("Invalid password");
          }
        }
        else
        {
          System.out.println("Incorrect Username!");
        }
        break;

      case 2:
        String na;
        int birthyear,age;
        System.out.println("Enter your name");
        na=a.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your birthyear");
        birthyear=a.nextInt();
        age=2016-birthyear;
        System.out.println(""+na+" your age is "+age);
        break;
      case 3:
        int deposit,withdrawal,balance;
        System.out.println("Enter your deposit;");
        deposit=a.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter your withdrawal:");
        withdrawal=a.nextInt();
        balance=deposit-withdrawal;

        if(balance<0){
          System.out.println("Your account balance is not enough!");
        }
        else
        {
          System.out.println("Your balance is:"+balance);
        }
        break;
      case 4:
        System.out.println("Thank you for using this program");
        break;
      default:
        System.out.println("Invalid Selection");
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You need to post what you have tried and what errors you are getting. Please read about asking on-topic questions in the [Help/On-Topic]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a do-while loop.

```
boolean continue = true;

do {
   // your switch statement here:

   // Ask for termination: Do you want to contine? y/n
   // set continue accordingly
} while(continue );
```

Your program will execute your switch at least once. Ask the user if he wants to continue and jumps back before the switch.

Answer (score 0):

while the user didn`t chose to exit (in your code, 4). print the options and let the user chose again.

```
do{
//your switch here
}while(choose!= EXIT_CODE);
```

Comment: You may want to explain your code. Only code answers will not help the asker understand the idea behind your code.